# Flutter beginner - first time seeing lots of constant blue problems in IDE

Tags: flutter, constants, new-project

My questions relates to this post:
[Flutter const with const constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554055/flutter-const-with-const-constructors)

I've got an issue trying to get rid of the blue squiggly lines under the majority of my widgets plus the MyApp class which I've never seen before. I prefix all the widgets with the const constructor but the issue just shifts to a different area of my code. I don't have this issue when coding in a different project so think it might be something outside the main.dart file.

Screenshots below illustrate errors and my fix attempts.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal[900],
        body:  SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child:  Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage('images/dice1.png'),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage('images/dice1.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/69310819/12413404

Comment: so possible duplicate of [Flutter 2.5 update - const keyword on every static Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69309972/flutter-2-5-update-const-keyword-on-every-static-widget)

Comment: sadly the fix mentioned in that question didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `const` keyword possibly highest in the widget tree. So if you've got three constant children inside a list (in a `Row` in your example), the whole list is a `const` itself.

If all children inside a list are constant, put `const` keyword right before the list.

So instead of this:

```
Row(
  children: [
    const Child1(),
    const Child2(),
    ...
  ],
)
```

Do this:

```
Row(
  children: const [
    Child1(),
    Child2(),
    ...
  ],
)
```

For more information see: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-const-redundantly

Comment: @FirentisTWF I did try this too but I didn't attach a screenshot of the error. I've updated my answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please read my answer carefully once again :) Put the `const` keyword in front of the list (after `children:`), not in front of the `Row` as it doesn't have a const constructor.

Comment: Oops, sorry! Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution to avoid const constructor. Go in your **analysis_options.yaml** file, and put this line at the bottom of the rule section

```
rule: 
  prefer_const_construtors: false,
```